# Windows won't ctrl+c and ctrl+v

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

Using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> I am unable to copy or paste anything.  I have tried many different applications and still no luck. I am able to copy/paste via the shortcut menu when you right click the mouse. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> works which means the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is functional.  I've tried restoring to an earlier restore point.  I also ran `SFC /SCANNOW` (System File Checker) which did not find any errors. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and then right click and paste doesn't work either. I have tried with external and internal keyboard and still no luck. I've clicked on all the relevant search results from Google but none of them work for me.

Does anyone know what may be causing this issue and how I can correct it?

This problem comes and goes at random times.

Comment: try using the Windows virtual keyboard to see if it is truly a hardware or software issue.

Comment: My guess would be that there is a sticky key.

Comment: sticky key I will try to look at it. Copying by right click and then copy works fine. The user could be clicking CTRL C and then nothing happen and then they try aging and then IT works fine.

Comment: probably some program with hot-key support

Comment: Yea maby, the issue is on many computers in the company, the isse came  when we got the new computer model from dell Latitude 7740.