# Ctrl+C not working on both Lubuntu and Windows

Tags: windows, ubuntu, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, lubuntu

Not sure what happened but about 2 weeks ago I noticed that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work anymore. Interestingly, <kbd>right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not work for capitalizing C but <kbd>left Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does.

So I am unable to copy text but I am also unable to kill programs using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> forcing me to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> and then `ps aux | grep whatever` then killing the pid.

I'm on Lubuntu 17 but this seems to be a deeper problem because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>right Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> also doesn't work in my Windows.

This began right around when I installed Lubuntu, however I am unsure if the timeline lines up exactly when I installed Lubuntu.

As a side note, I'm not sure if this means anything, but I just noticed that I have Fcitx installed in my Lubuntu Distro. Maybe this has something to do with it?

**How to fix it and make these key combinations regain their common meaning?**

Also, I've seen similar posts about this subject but none work in my case. I think this is something deeper than the Operating System level. Of course, I could be wrong.

UPDATE 1:
I should also mention that when I try to set the hotkeys for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, they won't work, meaning its like the keys don't even work (no input) for this combination. They won't set.

UPDATE 2:

This might be a Dell issue. I have Dell Lattitude 6410. The OP in this post: [Windows won't ctrl+c and ctrl+v](https://superuser.com/questions/728570/windows-wont-ctrlc-and-ctrlv?rq=1) states in the comments he is using Dell Lattitude 7740. But then again, this issue only just started for me a couple weeks ago

UPDATE 3:
The key combination works on another keyboard when plugged into the laptop.

UPDATE 4:

I followed the instructions in this post here: [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/a/1145369/432690).

I installed xinput, `sudo apt-get install xinput` then found my 'faulty' keyboard id from `xinput list`.

I ran `xinput 11` to test my keyboard inputs. As expected, input 'c' shows 'keypress 54', 'key release 54', and Ctrl shows the same with '37' however, unlike other key combinations, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> shows up empty ('keypress 37' shows up but is silent when pressing the c button in combination). <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on the external keyboard kills the program (xinput).

Comment: I mean when I boot into windows OS. The hotkeys don't work when I am in my Lubuntu OS and they don't work when I boot into windows either.

Comment: Thanks for the edits @kamil-maciorowski. That looks better.

Comment: I honestly don't think it has anything to do with the issue. I just through that out there because I've never seen that program in any of my other Linux Distros and I noticed the Fcitx program had Hotkey configurations in it. So I just through that out in case anyone may have had a run in with that program and had a similar experience.

Comment: This might be a Dell issue. I have Dell Lattitude 6410. The OP in this post: https://superuser.com/questions/728570/windows-wont-ctrlc-and-ctrlv?rq=1 states in the comments he is using Dell Lattitude 7740. But then again, this issue only just started for me a couple weeks ago.

Comment: Updated the question to add more useful information. But to answer your question, Yes, I want to fix the issue and make the key combination work so I may kill programs efficiently and copy text as well. I have an extra keyboard so I will plug it in and get back to you.

Comment: Woohoo! Making progress. The key combination does work when using another keyboard plugged into the laptop.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski, Question is updated to add that the external keyboard works with the key combination. Thanks for helping out teaching. If anything this is enlightening to know that an external keyboard works and bypasses the issue at hand.

Comment: I'm no expert in how keyboards work but the fact another keyboard works flawlessly makes me suspect there's something wrong with the keyboard itself or the keyboard controller. One mysterious thing is Ctrl+Z works and Ctrl+C doesn't; I don't know if this can be explained by a simple malfunction. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1145369/432690) and adapt it to your case. Maybe you will be able to investigate the problem little further and get to some conclusions.